# Nodejs URL Parameter Not Passing to POST Method

Tags: node.js, express

I am having an issue where my POST methods are not passing my URL parameters and instead using the dynamic parameter placeholder from the route path. Is this because I need to set that parameter as a hidden field in my form in order to use it in a POST method? I'm justing using the value for a query filter condition and not passing it as a value to my database record.

```
/*====   /RESET     ====*/

siteRoutes.route('/reset/:token')

    .get(function(req, res){
        models.User.findOne({
            where: {
                resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, //Returns the correct parameter
                resetPasswordExpires: {
                    $gt: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
                }
            }
        }).then(function(){
            res.render('pages/app/reset-password.hbs');
        })          
    })

    .post(function(req, res){
        async.waterfall([
            function(done){
                models.User.update({
                    password: req.body.password,
                    resetPasswordToken: undefined,
                    resetPasswordExpires: undefined
                }, { where: {
                    resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, //Returns ':token'
                    resetPasswordExpires: {
                        $gt: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
                    }
                }})
            // Nodemailer
            }
            ])
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
```

Example of the console log:

```
Executing (default): UPDATE `user` SET `password`='password',`updatedAt`='2016-04-03 18:57:14' WHERE `reset_password_token` = ':token' AND `reset_password_expires` > '2016-04-03 14:57:14'
```

Comment: What sort of value would you expect to be used in the query when `reset_password_token === undefined`? `NULL`? An empty string? Something else? You will need to set the `resetPassword*` fields to the appropriate/expected value instead of just `undefined`.

Comment: @mscdex the token is created from a different route with the function. The route here displays the resulting token from my function that matches the record on file, but when I try to submit a form for a new password the POST method doesn't find that parameter despite it being in the URL. `function(done){
   crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf){
    var resetToken = buf.toString('hex');
    done(err, resetToken);
   });`